# Web App Default Layout hides the bottom NavBar

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have been building a responsive Web Application that on loading with an address bar hides the bottom-most navbar. Is there a way to load it with the entire layout?

Here's how it should load:

[image: PC Load]

But here's how it loads on a smartphone:

[image: Default View]

However, when I scroll a little, it appears exactly as I want it to be:
[image]

I have used flex display as shown below: [I am using tailwind along with React JS]:

```
<div className='flex flex-col justify-around w-screen h-screen align-center'>
      {topNavBarprops ? (
        <TopNavBar {...topNavBarprops} />
      ) : (
        <TopNavBar headerText={'Unverified Account'} />
      )}
      <div className='flex flex-col flex-auto max-h-screen overflow-auto'>
        {childComponent}
      </div>

      <BottomNavBar />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your body/content div is too tall, likely pushed down by the top navbar, to resolve this, you can set the height value of the body/content div to be calc(100vh - `height of navbar here`)

Comment: Body height is actually vertical screen size. If I reduce it, while installing it as progressive web app it minifies keeping offset at the bottom